# Beginner Python problem with if statement

Tags: python-3.7

Apologies in advance because this is probably fairly stupid.

Basically I was just messing around trying to figure out how to work with inputs (I'm pretty new to coding) and I came across an issue within an if statement.

```
x=input("What is your name? ")
name=x
print("Hello,", name, "nice to meet you")
y=input("Would you like me to close now? (yes/no) ")
listx=["no","No","NO","nO"]
for response in listx:
    if response == y:
        input("Why? ")
        input("I think you're being rather terse", name, ". ")
        input("No, you. ")
        input("So that's how it's going to be? ")
        input("Well I'm closing anyway. ")
        input("Bye then. ")
```

I kind of just thought it would take me through this funny little exchange and over time I could customise the responses but there's a problem at this point:

```
input("I think you're being rather terse", name, ". ")
```

At this juncture the code doesn't seem to recognise name; I defined name because it wasn't working when I just used x either. I'm assuming that the code doesn't recognise it because the if statement is essentially within a vacuum or something but how exactly would I work around this? I want to be able to call back details which happened previously within the conversation to try to make it funnier.

Comment: Rule 1 when debugging (and especially when asking for help with debugging) is to show the evidence, i.e. the actual symptoms (do you get an error message? unexpected output? if so, what is the output?), not your interpretation of what's going on ("*the code doesn't seem to recognise name*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `input()` statements - it only works with `print()`. So `print()` can take *any number* of strings as an argument, but `input()` will only take one (and in recent versions of python will raise an error if you try to give it more than one - when I tried to run your code myself, I got a `TypeError`).

If you want to include `name` in the text of the `input()`, you'll need to either *concatenate* it:

```
input("I think you're being rather terse " + name + ". ")
```

or use a format string to insert it:

```
input(f"I think you're being rather terse {name}. ")
```